# Awk only works on final file

Tags: bash, csv, parsing, awk

I am attempting to process many .csv files using the following loop:

```
for i in *.csv
do
    dos2unix $i
    awk '{print $0, FILENAME}' $i>new_edit.csv
done
```

This script shoud append the file name, to the end of each file, and it works. However, looking at the output new_edit.csv only contains data from one of the .csv files entered.

```
wc -l new_edit.csv
```

Indicates that my awk is only processing lines from one of my csv files. How can I make my awk process every file?

Comment: Looking at the output in new_edit.csv, I suspect its overwriting instead of appending to the file since its only the last file that seems to be in there, but I'm not sure....

Comment: Exactly. It should be `... $i >> new_edit.csv`.

Comment: @JamesBrown Your comment fixes my issue. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You could also replace the whole thing with `awk '{sub(/\r/,"",$NF); print $0, FILENAME}' *.csv > new_edit.csv`.

Comment: @JamesBrown Why is your replacement awk advantageous over what I'm doing?

Comment: It uses awk only and doesn't mix shell script with awk.

Comment: I see, it removes the need for a for loop.

Comment: You could also simply set RS and then no need for sub command either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `>` you should use `>>` as appending redirector. You could also replace the whole code with:

`$ awk '{sub(/\r/,"",$NF); print $0, FILENAME}' *.csv > new_edit.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Following program should help you:
since you were using the redirect operator `>` , which was always overriding the content in file. if we replace it with append redirect oprerator **`>>`**, it would process all files and append the content in new file

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.csv
do
          awk '{print $0, FILENAME}' $i>>new_edit.csv
done
```